# how to "one column of table minus 1"?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a TABLE named FLY,i have a column in it named FLY_NUM.im trying to decrease the value of this column in a mysql query(in PHP).
something like this :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE fly SET  `fly_Num` = `fly_Num` -1 WHERE fly_ID ='1' ");
```

this is wrong!everytime this query run,FLY_NUM column set to zero.how can i do such a thing?

Comment: Your query is working fine for me. Maybe there is something else wrong.

Comment: Is the update query in a php loop?

Comment: If you still have this problem can you paste your actual code?

Answer (score 4):

Your query is valid and correct. There is also no need to put a space between the `-` and the `1`.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE fly (fly_id int, fly_num int);

INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 6);
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, 7);
```

Update Query:

```
UPDATE fly SET `fly_Num` = `fly_Num` -1 WHERE fly_id ='1';

Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 7  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0
```

New table contents:

```
SELECT * FROM fly;

+--------+---------+
| fly_id | fly_num |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       0 |
|      1 |       1 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
|      1 |       5 |
|      1 |       6 |
+--------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It works even if you use a `varchar` for the `fly_num` column:

```
CREATE TABLE fly (fly_id int, fly_num varchar(10));

INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '1');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '2');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '3');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '4');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '5');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '6');
INSERT INTO fly VALUES (1, '7');
```

Update Query:

```
UPDATE fly SET `fly_Num` = `fly_Num` -1 WHERE fly_id ='1';

Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 7  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0
```

New table contents:

```
SELECT * FROM fly;

+--------+---------+
| fly_id | fly_num |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       0 |
|      1 |       1 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      1 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
|      1 |       5 |
|      1 |       6 |
+--------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Notice that fly_Num and fly_ID are not the same.

Comment: @Sjoerd: You're right, I didn't notice. I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes buddy,i did it too.
i run it as a sql query in phpmyadmin and it works fine,but in my php query it will set column to zero!!!!!!
i copied the exact query in my codes!
what is problem?!

Comment: Very strange. Let's see if someone comes with any new ideas... I can't think of any :)

Comment: i discovered new thing about this problem,everytime this query runs in my php code,it will decrease column by 3!!!!!!!
i tried my query as this : "...  `fly_Num` = `fly_Num` -3  ..."
and my value decreased 9 times.it means if i had 20 in this column,it changed to 11

Comment: @armin: That really looks like your php code is being executed x3 times.

Comment: no Daniel.i had run it in single php file with no extra codes!!!!
but it still wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your PHP code.

Are you running this in a loop? Another way of asking this would be do you do anything special in you code when fly_num = 0? Phpmyadmin uses the same mysql connector as you code so the problem must be in your code not in your query.

**NOTE:** Another possible problem in your PHP is that you're including the file **multiple times**.

Every time its included it will call the database and decrement by 1.

Comment: no,i tried it in a single file,that just doing this query!
but the problem is still!!!
i discovered new thing about this problem,everytime this query runs in my php code,it will decrease column by 3!!!!!!!
i tried my query as this : "...  `fly_Num` = `fly_Num` -3  ..."
and my value decreased 9 times.it means if i had 20 in this column,it changed to 11 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
my mind is blowing!!!

Comment: I've updated my answer because I think that this may be easier to understand.

Comment: @armin: that obviously means you are calling the update three times per id